# different workspaces in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: workspaces

I have 2 workspaces in ubuntu 18.04.I want   have different workspace in each screen but the workspaces join by together

Comment: does [this extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/921/multi-monitors-add-on/) help?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this is not how it works in Gnome Shell.

By default, one monitor has the work spaces, the second monitor is a static extension of the space on the first monitor. Thus, if you switch workspaces, the display of the other monitor does not alter.

Gnome Tweaks has a setting where you can alter the behaviour such that the second monitor is an extension of the space of the currently active workspace on the first monitor. Then, both monitors simultaneously will change view when you switch workspaces.

Unfortunately, that is it. It is not out of the box possible to have one workspace allocated to one monitor, like it works in for example i3 window manager.